# Sequelize cyclic dependencies?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Okay, so I attempted to create a `hasMany`/`belongsTo` relationship between two entities `User` and `Submission`, and got the classic `Cyclic dependency found. users is dependent of itself. Dependency chain: users -> submissions => users`

As with seemingly everyone else on the internet, I just put `constraints: false` on every relation. Like, every single one in the whole app.

I'm still getting the exact same error.

```
    User.associate = models => {
        User.hasMany(models.Submission, { 
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            constraints: false
        })
    }

    Submission.associate = models => {
        Submission.belongsTo(models.User, { 
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            constraints: false
        })
    }
```

Does anyone know what to do in this context? I obviously can't remove any more constraints. It's the world's most basic relationship, I cannot work out why Sequelize is throwing a tantrum.